# How to quickly transform a List(Of Object) into a List(Of "Object.field")?

Tags: vb.net, linq, list

Suppose I have a list of Cat.

```
Public Class Cat 
    Public Property id As Guid
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property race As catRace
End Class
```

How can I quickly transform this List(Of Cat) into a List(Of Guid) using the id property?

I could do :

```
Dim newList As List(Of Guid)
For each item in catList
    newList.Add(item.id)
Next
```

But I think there must be a way to do this faster (1 LOC). I just can't find how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One line of code, using extension methods rather than LINQ.

```
newList = catList.Select(Function(t) t.id).ToList
```

If you prefer LINQ

```
newList = (From c In catList Select c.id).ToList
```

Answer (score 2):

One line of code may make it faster to type, but it won't necessarily be faster to execute.

```
Dim newList = From c In catList Select c.id
```

Answer (score 1):

LINQ. catList.Select(t=>t.id). Not entirely sure what VB equivalent of => is for the lambda though.